# Why is ESLint complaining about @inheritdoc tag?

Tags: typescript, eslint, jsdoc

ESLint is complaining about a missing JSDoc return declaration even though I placed there an `@inheritdoc` tag:

[image]

This is the relevant part of the interface I am inheriting from:

```
export interface L2BlockSource {
  /**
   * Gets the sync status of the L2 block source.
   * @returns The sync status of the L2 block source.
   */
  getSyncStatus(): SyncStatus;
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think ESlint is not showing the actual problem. Try removing the logic from the parent class method leaving only an empty return.